# Android SQLite - ExecSQL syntax error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am completely at lost on what is the syntax error with this create table statement. It is one of the 5 tables that I am creating, 4 created successfully but this one is failing

Here is the create statement

```
//String to create a transaction table
private static final String CREATE_TRANSACTION_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TRANSACTION_TABLE + "("
                + Constants.COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + Constants.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_ID + " INTEGER, "
                + Constants.COLUMN_DATE_CREATED + " BIGINT, "
                + Constants.COLUMN_SUB_TOTAL_AMOUNT + " NUMERIC, "
                + Constants.COLUMN_LINE_ITEMS + " TEXT, "
                + Constants.COLUMN_TAX_AMOUNT + " NUMERIC, "
                + Constants.COLUMN_TOTAL_AMOUNT + " NUMERIC, "
                + Constants.COLUMN_LAST_UPDATED + " BIGINT, "
                + "FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customer(_id)" + ")";
```

And below is the stack trace with the error highlighted

```
08-24 19:13:25.376  10608-10608/com.okason.prontopos D/DatabaseHelper﹕ CREATE TABLE category(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT NOT NULL, image_path TEXT, create_date BIGINT, last_update_date BIGINT )
08-24 19:13:25.376  10608-10608/com.okason.prontopos D/DatabaseHelper﹕ CREATE TABLE customer(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT, phone TEXT, street1 TEXT, street2 TEXT, city TEXT, state TEXT, zip TEXT create_date BIGINT, last_update_date BIGINT, points NUMERIC )
08-24 19:13:25.376  10608-10608/com.okason.prontopos D/DatabaseHelper﹕ CREATE TABLE retailer(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT, phone TEXT, street1 TEXT, street2 TEXT, city TEXT, state TEXT, zip TEXT, industry TEXT, create_date BIGINT, last_update_date BIGINT, manager_name TEXT )
08-24 19:13:25.376  10608-10608/com.okason.prontopos D/DatabaseHelper﹕ CREATE TABLE product(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT NOT NULL, description TEXT, price NUMERIC, image_path TEXT, category_id INTEGER, create_date BIGINT, last_update_date BIGINT, FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES category(_id))
08-24 19:13:25.380  10608-10608/com.okason.prontopos D/DatabaseHelper﹕ CREATE TABLE transaction(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,customer_id INTEGER, create_date BIGINT, sub_total_amount NUMERIC, items TEXT, tax_amount NUMERIC, total_amount NUMERIC, last_update_date BIGINT, FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customer(_id))


08-24 19:13:25.380  10608-10608/com.okason.prontopos E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "transaction": syntax error
08-24 19:13:25.380  10608-10608/com.okason.prontopos E/DatabaseHelper﹕ near "transaction": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE transaction(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,customer_id INTEGER, create_date BIGINT, sub_total_amount NUMERIC, items TEXT, tax_amount NUMERIC, total_amount NUMERIC, last_update_date BIGINT, FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customer(_id))null
```

Answer (score 3):

`transaction` is a keyword in SQL. To use it as an identifier, you need to quote it e.g. in double quotes as `"transaction"`. Or just rename your table to e.g. `transactions` to make it a non-keyword identifier.

Comment: Side note: Normalization rules (and common sense) want all table names to be `plurals`.